# change <p> to input value when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this code 
HTML

```
    <h2 class="p1">Player 1</h2>
    <input type="text" class="addName1" value="Player 1"></input><button class="addName1b">Add name</button>
```

Jquery

```
$('.addName1b').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('addName1b');
    if ($this.hasClass('addName1b')) {
        $this.text('Add name');
    } else {
        $this.text('Change name');
    }
    $('.addName1').toggle();
    $(/*TEXT FROM INPUT*/).appendTo(".p1");
});
```

I want the Player 1 to change into the text from the input box when I press the button but can't figure out how. Help please :) 
As you can see I was planning on using .appendTo but I don't know how to access the text from the input element.

Thanks

Comment: Quote from W3C: "If you use the "button" tag, always set the type of it. Different browsers use different default types for them."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it this line of code

```
 $('.p1').text($('.addName1').val());
```

in the place where you have `$(/*TEXT FROM INPUT*/).appendTo(".p1");`

`appendTo` is not the right choice for your goal here, `appendTo` is used to append elements into another, but your requirement is to change the text of the element, you must use `.text()`

Here is a working snippet.

```js
$('.addName1b').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('addName1b');
    if ($this.hasClass('addName1b')) {
        $this.text('Add name');
    } else {
        $this.text('Change name');
    }
    $('.addName1').toggle();
    $('.p1').text($('.addName1').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="p1">Player 1</h2>
    <input type="text" class="addName1" value="Player 1"></input><button class="addName1b">Add name</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Used a variable to store the new name,
- Got the new name from the input using `.val()`
- Reversed the last line because the selector `$('.p1')`goes first then the value is last `(newName)`.
- There's no parentheses because it's a variable representing a string.

Change the last two lines to this:

```
 var newName = $('.addName1').val();
$(".p1").text(newName);
```

```js
$(function() {
  
$('.addName1b').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('addName1b');
    if ($this.hasClass('addName1b')) {
        $this.text('Add name');
    } else {
        $this.text('Change name');
    }

    var newName = $('.addName1').val();
    $(".p1").text(newName);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>


<h2 class="p1">Player 1</h2>
<input type="text" class="addName1" value="Player 1" />
<button class="addName1b">Add name</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some framework?) Something like angular, knockout, reactjs? Excellent for something like this purposes.

But. For reading input value you can use something like:

```
  $('#id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Input does not close like this

```
<h2 class="p1">Player 1</h2>
<input type="text" class="addName1" value="Player 1"></input><button class="addName1b">Add name</button>
```

just

```
<input .... />
```

Your JS - modified

```
$('.addName1b').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $input_val = $('.addName1').val();
    $this.toggleClass('addName1b');
    if ($this.hasClass('addName1b')) {
        $this.text('Add name');
    } else {
        $this.text('Change name');
    }
    $('.addName1').toggle();
    $('.p1').text($input_val);
});
```

here's jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qgumjy7b/

Hope this helps to understand what are you missing.